# How can I change the way links look and act in my Rails 3 application?

Tags: hyperlink, ruby-on-rails-3

I have brands and products, and there is a nightly load that replaces them. A brand may end up with a new id, and a product will *always* end up with a new id. But I have customers that want static links to these dynamic ids.

I would like a link that now looks like:

.mysite.com/brands/17/products/168390

to look like:

.mysite.com/products/ABC123

where "ABC123" is an alphanumeric identifier not associated with the id. Think of it like a model number.

I don't need anyone to give me the answer, I am happy to do the work. But any pointers to where I can get started would help, as I apparently don't have the right terminology to do a successful Google search.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest watching the screencasts done by Ryan Bates at [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/).

For your question on how to change the products URL away from id, the specific ones would be [Model Name in URL](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url) or [Semi-Static Pages](http://railscasts.com/episodes/117-semi-static-pages) (just the information on how the routing is accomplished).  For your question on the shortening the nested URLS, what you want would be his cast on [Nested Resources](http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources).

Those are the ones that have to do with your specific problems, however I would suggest watching all of them in order to learn more about the framework.  One thing to note is that since those are fairly old, things may have changed some in Rails 3, however I imagine that once you get something to Google, you will be able to find how to do it in Rails 3 fairly easily.

Answer (score 1):

Do it using rails routes.  Something like:

```
  match 'products/code/:product_code' => 'products#code'
```

There are lots of things you can do with routes - my suggestion would be to familiarize yourself with them.